# Как с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить адрес сайта?

Tags: python, python-2.7

У меня есть список, в списке к примеру адреса по такому типу:

```
https://www.example.com/releases?release_type=stock_exchange_release
https://www.example.org/our-services/services-near-me
https://example.hu/en/
https://example.pitt.edu/en/
http://www.example.org.uk/index.php/blog?tid=Al
```

Как с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить из списка www.example.com www.example.org example.hu www.example.org.uk и т.п?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше воспользоваться [специально предназначенным для этого инструментом](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse  # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse      # Python 2.x

urls = ['https://www.example.com/releases?release_type=stock_exchange_release'
'https://www.example.org/our-services/services-near-me',
'https://example.hu/en/',
'https://example.pitt.edu/en/',
'http://www.example.org.uk/index.php/blog?tid=Al']

res = [urlparse(u).netloc for u in urls]
print(res)
```

результат:

```
['www.example.com', 'example.hu', 'example.pitt.edu', 'www.example.org.uk']
```

Comment: если автору порт не нужен, то вместо netloc, можно hostname использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать посплитить по слешам:

```
'http://example.com/asdasd'.split('/')[2] # example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from re import findall
s = '''https://www.example.com/releases?release_type=stock_exchange_release
https://www.example.org/our-services/services-near-me
https://example.hu/en/
https://example.pitt.edu/en/
http://www.example.org.uk/index.php/blog?tid=Al'''
print findall('https?://([^/]+)', s)
```